# In ProcessMaker 4, what is Process Manager?

Tags: processmaker

In ProcessMaker 4, when configuring a process at Designer/Processes/Configuration, there is a new parameter "Process Manager" that is not described in the
[documentation](https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/designing-processes/viewing-processes/view-the-list-of-processes/edit-the-name-description-category-or-status-of-a-process#configure-general-settings).

Where is the documentation for what "Process Manager" is/what it allows/what responsibilities it has?

Answer (score 0):

Find the documentation related to Process Manager here:

https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/v/processmaker-1/designing-processes/viewing-processes/view-the-list-of-processes/edit-the-name-description-category-or-status-of-a-process#configure-general-settings

Here is the expected behavior and description for this feature:

> From the Process Manager drop-down menu, select which user is the
> Process Manager. The Process Manager understands the Process design
> and workflow dynamics to troubleshoot Request routing incidents. This
> setting is only available if the Advanced User package is installed.
> This user is assigned Tasks in this Process's Requests in which
> workflow would otherwise pause indefinitely because that Request's
> workflow cannot continue to a valid Task assignee for any of the
> following reasons:
>
> - The Request routes to a Task assignee whose user account is inactive.
> - The Request routes to the Task assignee's manager, but that user's       account is not configured with a manager.
> - The Task assignee does not have a user account manager, and is a    member of two or more groups which have different managers.
> - The Request routes to a Task assignee in which that user's account is set with the following statuses:
> - The user's account is set to Out of Office status, but not configured with a delegated user to assign new Tasks while with this
>   status.
> - The user's account is set to Scheduled status, is not scheduled to    work    when the Task is assigned, and is not configured with a
>   delegated    user to assign new Tasks.
>
> The Process Manager is assigned the Task in that Request, and may then
> indicate how to route that Request. The Process Manager may optionally
> cancel that Request if that user is among those selected in the Cancel
> Request setting.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.